# split dataframe based on column value

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a df that contains several IDs, I´m trying to run a regression to the data and I need to be able to split it by ID to apply the regression to each ID:

Sample DF (this is only a sample real data is larger)

[image]

I tried to save the ID´s within a list like this:

```
id_list = []

for data in df['id'].unique():
    id_list.append(data)
```

The list output is [1,2,3]

Then I was trying to use that to sort the DF:

```
def create_dataframe(df):

    for unique_id in id_list:
        df = df[df['Campaign ID'] == campaign_id]
        return df
```

when I call the function the result is:

[image]

However I only got the result for the first ID in the list ,the other 2 [2,3] are not returning any DF... which means that at some point the loop breaks.

Here it is the entire code:

```
 df = pd.read_csv('budget.csv')

 id_list = []

 for unique_id in df['id'].unique():
     id_list.append(unique_id)


 def create_dataframe(df):

        for unique_id in id_list:
            df = df[df['Campaign ID'] == unique_id]
            return df

 print(create_dataframe(df))
```

Comment: please post your expected output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the code snippet `df.loc[df['id'] == item]` to extract sub dataframes based on a particular value of a column in the dataframe.

Please refer the full code below

```
import pandas as pd

df_dict = {"id" : [1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3],
           "value" : [12,13,14,22,23,24,32,33,34]
           }

df = pd.DataFrame(df_dict)
print(df)
id_list = []
for data in df['id'].unique():
    id_list.append(data)

print(id_list)

for item in id_list:
    sub_df = df.loc[df['id'] == item]
    print(sub_df)
    print("****")
```

The following output will be generated for this with the requirement of getting the sub dataframes for each of the distinct column ids

```
 id  value
0   1     12
1   1     13
2   1     14
3   2     22
4   2     23
5   2     24
6   3     32
7   3     33
8   3     34
[1, 2, 3]
   id  value
0   1     12
1   1     13
2   1     14
****
   id  value
3   2     22
4   2     23
5   2     24
****
   id  value
6   3     32
7   3     33
8   3     34
****
```

Now in your code snippet the issue was that the function createdataframe() is getting called only once and inside the function when we iterate through the elements, after fetching the details of the sub df for id =1 you have used a return statement to return this df. Hence you are getting only the sub df for id = 1.

Comment: Thanks... you were right the fact that I was calling the function just once, after perform the changes the code worked.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be overnighting the `df` value in the for loop. I would recommend moving the df creation outside of the for loop and then append to it there. Then adding to it in each of the loops instead of overwriting it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`numpy.split`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.split.html):

```py
df.sort_values('id', inplace=True)
np.split(df, df.index[df.id.diff().fillna(0).astype(bool)])
```

or pandas [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html):

```py
grp = df.groupby('id')
[grp.get_group(g) for g in df.groupby('id').groups]
```

Although I think you can make a regression directly using pandas `groupby`, since it logically apply any function you want taking each group as a distinct dataframe.